# iOS Sliding UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a similar implementation like this: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel
but for iOS. Currently I have a ViewController with a UITableView. I override this method so I can expand the list on tap:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected: \(indexPath.row)")
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        self.mTableViewTopConstant.constant = 200
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

What I want now is this: if the list is expanded and the scroll position is at the top, when I move down my finger (fast swipe) on the list, the list should collapse. Also if it's possible when I'm moving my finger the list should follow my direction. I've dig into the UIScrollViewDelegate, but I didn't find a method which fires while scrolling the list. Is there any?

Comment: Is that what you mean? Or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: Thanks, gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You did not find a method that fires while scrolling in UIScrollViewDelegate?!? :-)

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

- scrollViewDidScroll:
- scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
- scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
- scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
- scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
- scrollViewDidScrollToTop:

Choose one mate :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe I didn't explain it correct. These events fires only once. I need an event that will continuously fire while I'm scrolling (without leaving my finger) and report the current offSet.